# How to implement one time password for download

Tags: php, one-time-password

I need some advice in php, How can I make that users will be able to download file just one time with password which they get from me.

First, I will need some connected database with list of unique passwords. 
Then using php I must detect, if password was used for download - if yes, disable it.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Assign some random number to user and store it in database

Comment: [Too broad I'm afraid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to maintain one field in database so that when user click next time, it won't get downloaded.

This is how I do:
When I send link:

```
 $email_enc = base64_encode($check[0]->email_id);
    $id_enc = base64_encode($check[0]->id);
    $time = time();
    $url = $baseurl . "downloadfile?unq=" . $id_enc . "&em=" . $email_enc . "&tm=" . $time;

    $emaildata['message'] = "Hello $name,<br/><br/> Please <a href='$url'>Click</a> here to download your attachment.<br/><br/> Thanks,<br/>XYZ";
    sendmail($emaildata);
   //set status to 0
```

When user Clicks on link:

```
if ($_REQUEST['unq'] != '' && $_REQUEST['em'] != '' && $_REQUEST['tm'] != '') 
{
  $unique_id = base64_decode($_REQUEST['unq']);
  $u_email = base64_decode($_REQUEST['em']);
  $email_para = array(
    'id' => $unique_id
  );
  $check_avaibility = $this->User_model->getAnyData($email_para);
  if (!empty($check_avaibility)) 
  {
    $u_time = $_REQUEST['tm'];
    $cur_time = time();
    if ($cur_time - $u_time < 10800)
    {
      if(//check status to 0 only)
      {
       //download attachment
       //update the status as 1 that means link is not clickable next time
      }
    }
  }
}
```